# Split screen mode causes error with FragmentTabHost

Tags: android, android-support-library

I have an Android application using the support library v13. I updated this to version 25.1.1 to try and solve this error but it still happens. When I attempt to put my application into split screen mode it crashes.

I have spent hours debugging and I see the issue. My `FragmentActivity` is created again when this happens. That in turn calls `setContentView()`. That in turn inflates and adds views. Eventually I end up in `FragmentTabHost.onAttachedToWindow()`. This contains the line:

```
ft = doTabChanged(currentTab, ft);
```

The `currentTab` is null at this point though. This is because the tabs are added in Java, not in the XML file. This throws the error "No tab known for tag null".

This does work fine when the application is opened for the first time because this code doesn't seem to ever get hit.

Any insights would be very much appreciated.

**[EDIT]**: Comment #35 [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78772) is the same thing. They say it was fixed in support library 25.0 but it is not.

**[EDIT]**: I "fixed" this by blocking split screen mode in the application. That's really a bad fix but it does stop the error from happening.

Comment: Entering or exiting a multi-window mode is just a configuration change, not significantly different than any other one (e.g., screen rotation). Do you get this behavior for other configuration changes?

Comment: No. This does not happen in any other case. This application has been in the Play Store for 5 years. It has gone through updates throughout this time, but this error only happens when entering split screen.

Comment: OK, now, *that's* strange. If you wind up creating a reproducible test case (e.g., for filing your own issue, given that the one you cited is now closed), I'd be happy to take a peek at it.